# Infer number of comets, based upon observations of their periodic visits to Earth

Tags: algorithms

Can we algorithmically infer the number of comets that orbit the Earth, based upon periodic observations of them, if we cannot tell the comets apart?  In more detail:

#### The problem

- There is an unknown, fixed number of comets, `numComets` that pass by
  Earth and are visible from the ground.
- Each comet takes a fixed number of years to orbit Earth.
- Based only on this knowledge and the dates recorded that a comet was
  sighted in the night sky, determine `numComets`, **AND** determine
  the orbital period of each comet. You can use an unlimited amount of
  observation data (time), but the solution in the shortest amount of
  time is preferable.

#### Assumptions you can make

- All comets look identical from the ground; there is no way to
  visually identify them.
- No other object will be mistaken for a comet, and all comets will be
  seen.
- No comet takes more than 100 years to orbit Earth, and no new comets
  will be introduced.

As current answers have pointed out, the problem as it lay now is unsolvable. Would a solution be possible if `numComets` is known? (Even roughly get the right answer?) What modifications to the problem would have to be made otherwise, to still encasulate the spirit of the problem, and make it solvable? (or is it dead with no hope of solving accurately?)

#### Further assumption

All comets start at a different point in their orbit. I.e. They do not all start their orbit at the same place like racehorses coming out of a gate.

#### Clarification

Comets are only recorded once per year. So there is no difference between a comet that passes at the beginning of a year and at the end. The problem could just as easily have been worded as days.

Comment: It seems clear from your last sentence that you would not recognize an answer if you saw one. You state your problem as involving only integers, and that has consequences.

Comment: Could be you more specific, rather than just plain rude?

Comment: @HCBPshenanigans babou's comment it not rude, it's merely an estimation of your level of knowledge/skill and concludes that he thinks we can't help you. (I won't comment on whether he's right).

Comment: Regarding your edit, please don't shout. Emphasising formatting should be used sparlingly. Also, posts should always be "wholesome"; please integrate changes into the original post as opposed to keep adding material at the bottom.

Comment: @Raphael Wasn't shouting in my edit. Sorry if it looked that way. Just bolded to make sure people would notice it. Anyways, I'm not saying that he is wrong, but does it not seem a little rude to just swing by and say that you are too dumb to help? If he would've said, "I can't really explain that without you knowing more about x, because you said in the problem y, which doesn't work because of x." Or more specifically, what consequence is he speaking of? That is what I mean. It just seems like a hit and run insult. No hard feelings though! And thank you for the tips on edit, will take note.

Comment: About rudeness, you started using boldface in a form that is perceived
as shouting. I referred explicitly to your boldface sentence on
hose-racing, which seems directed at @Raphael 's comment. It turns out
that if you assume that orbits are an integral number of years, the
horse-race gate situation is bound to occurs at some point, which you
can chose as time 0, since time 0 is arbitrary anyway. This is an
elementary property of integers. So you question started by
disqualifying the unavoidable, which leaves no room for sensible answer.

Comment: @Babou I now see what you mean. No hard feelings!

Comment: Actually, the horse race gate situation is unavoidable when obital
times are prime to each other, not if two of them have a common
divider. For example if 2 comets have periods 2 years and 6 years, and
appear once at a one year interval, then they will never appear
the same year.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Based on the restriction you gave, that you cannot identify one comet from another, there is no difinative method of calculation. Here is a proposed situation, There are 2 comets following the same trajectory, they each orbit at exactly ten year orbit durations, so each one is seen every ten years, they are however exactly 5 years apart in their orbits. From the ground if we cannot differentiate between these two comets we only see a comet appear overhead regularly every 5 years, there is no way to tell if this is one comet appearing ever 5 years, or two comets appearing every ten years, but 5 years apart. From this it is impossible to deterministically say how many comets there are, so no algorithm can give you numComets with the assumptions that you have specified.

Comment: D'oh! Although this answer is actually useful. It is just as useful to know the types of problems that cannot be solved as the ones that can. What if we said that an error of this sort was allowable? We are just looking for general correctness.

Comment: If numComets was known, would this make the resulting calculations possible?

Comment: @HCBPshenanigans I think yes, assuming all comets start at year 0 (wlog; at some point, namely the smallest common multiple of their orbits, their observations coincide), via solving the system of equations like $\sum_{i=1}^C [o_i \mod y = 0] = c_y$ (sum a one for each comet that visits in year $y$; has to equal count of comets in that year $c_y$.)

Comment: Addendum: time zero is not attainable in the way I claimed; comets with the same orbit time miss each other forever. I think you can add this to the equation system, though.

Answer (score 1):

Observations begin with year 0.

Let $c_{i,j}$ the number of comets sighted the first time on year $j$ that have an $i$ years orbit, with $i\in[1,100]$ and $j\in [0,i-1]$.
Let $n_k$ be the number of comets sighted on year $k$.

Each year of observation gives an equation:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{100}c_{i,k\bmod i}=n_k$$

The total number of comets is $$\sum_{i=1}^{100}\sum_{j=0}^{i-1}c_{i,j}$$

There are $100\times 101/2=5050\; $ variables, so one could think that this number of years of observation would give enough equations. But it is likely that many equations will turn out to be linear conbinations of others. On the other hand, this will be a system of [linear Diophantine equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_equation) (i.e. using only integers). In this case, resolution may not require as many equations as there are variables.

To be sure to observe everything, it is better to do it until the set
of comets return to its initial configuration, which is  after a number of years that is the least common multiple of the first hundred integers: I have not computed it, but it seems to be somewhat longer than the current age of the universe (probably even when measured in seconds - it broke my LCM calculator). But as [Tycho-Brahe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tycho_Brahe) taught us, astronomy is a science for the patient.

Maybe a better analysis would show that less years may be needed (I
doubt it, but I am not sure). Else, we just get an
approximation, or improve the precision of the solution as time goes by and more observations are available. Anyway, we know that there is some indeterminacy in the
problem that prevents distinguishing an obit from its harmonics, as remarked in [another answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/28832#28833). So we
know we will not get enough linearly independent equations anyway.

Well, once we have the equations, we solve them as much as possible,
and get a set of possible answers, depending on a few remaining
variables that can be freely chosen.

Then we can impose a further constraint on the total number, which  reduces by one the degree of freedom on the answer.

This is probably not be a complete resolution of the problem. Only integer solutions are
acceptable, and it is not clear to me that resolving the equations give
only integer answers.

Systems of linear equations are normally solved over a field, and
integers do not form a field. So some of the solutions found will be
rational numbers, as rationals do form a field. But that is not
acceptable. Some integer solutions must exist, though, as it is an
hypothesis of the question: parameters of the problem result from
observation of a solution (except for the total number of comets which can only be given by an oracle). So integer solutions will have to be
extracted from the set of rational solutions, I suppose with
divisibility considerations.

But my memory of the properties of [linear
diophantines systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_equation) and their resolution is gone, whatever it was at an earlier age.
So I leave this for someone else, unless I find enough information on the web, and the time to read it.

This calls for a few remarks.

- It is not a problem of algorithmics but of formalization.
- The OP obviously knew the solution before he asked

His strange behavior made me react. I am wary of technical questions
supposedly naive, because the asker is often gone when I post the
answer, not to come back ... and I hate it. Then the reaction
of the OP gave me the clue: he knew. That was motivating.

I have an excuse: I am not a native speaker. What is the meaning of HCBP?

Comment: Haha, HCBP stands for Hard Core Battlefield Players. Stupid little video game clan I made up when I was much younger. I guess it just kinda stuck.

Comment: And babou, I did not know the answer to the problem when I asked. I merely thought of a possible problem that got me curious; I was thinking of how people figured this out long ago, and wanted to relate my question to programming. But I am glad to have motivated you! Honestly though, it was just a dumb question I had.

Comment: @HCBPshenanigans At first, it looked like many supposedly naive questions that keep
changing as people try to answer them and see problems. On some
occasions, I spent hours answering a question that kept changing over
time, from a fellow who obviously did not know what he wanted, and did
not really seem to understand his own problem and its limitations. As
a reasult, we too often tend to answer too quickly, if at all, unless
we find the issue catchy enough, which was not my case here. But I
still find it hard to believe this was an idle question, without a
further motivation.

Comment: On the other hand, Diophantine equations were the first to be analyzed
historically, afaik. Then it should not be too much of a surprise that
a "naive" or "dumb" question would hit that subject ... even though
the ancient mathematicians were neither naive nor dumb. But, of
course, comets were never studied that way. Calendars were quite good
pretty early in history. Ahem ... if you are so new to the issue, how
did you know that @Raphael 's hypothesis did not necessarily hold, since
you kept excluding it?

Comment: I dunno, it just didn't make sense. It didn't seem complete. I can't really give specifics. As you said, I am quite ignorant of this topic. It took me a good 20 minutes to figure out the equation you posted, and I'm still not sure I get it; I'd like to think I'm quite good at math but this thread shows that I still have college ahead of me.

Comment: But if you wish to keep viewing me as some grandmaster of this subject secretly posing as a peon to pose a question to his disciples, please, continue, haha. :) I'll take that title.

Comment: @HCBPshenanigans Grandmaster, no. But I would do this kind of things,
possibly with expert help, if I were a sociologist, for example. This
kind, and a few other. I would be extremely surprise that no
sociologist is logged in as normal user on SE sites. I am afraid there
may even be worse than sociologists. - - - It's no surprise my
equation was hard to read, since there was a bug, now corrected. If
you are really new to algorithms, that is another thing they share
with proofs ... it takes a while to weed out the bugs, even when the
problem is well understood.

Answer (score 0):

Let $t_1, t_2, ...$ be the times that comets were seen, in reverse chronological order (that is $t_1$ is the latest).

Start with comet $t_1$, and consider all *candidates* that were seen before. For example, if you assume that $t_2$ is the same comet as $t_1$, then the period is $T = t_1 - t_2$. Now all you need to do is to check whether there was a comet at times $t_1 - 2T$, $t_1 - 3T$, etc (depending on how rigorous you want to be). If not, then go to the next candidate ($t_3$, and so on).  If yes, then congratulations -- you established that comet $t_1$ has period $T$. Exclude this comet together with all its previous sightings $t_1 - kT$ from your dataset. If the dataset is not empty (not all comets have been identified yet), then start from the beginning.

Comment: Except that this will not work for the reason stated above, this method can confuse 2 comets each with period $T$ orbiting $T/2$ years apart as one with period $T/2$.

Comment: One may still want to approximate the result, up to known limitations. So this is not absurd. But it may not be the best approach.

Comment: The problem is that this is arbitrarily bad, Say I have 100 comets at periods 100 years each one after the other, this gives again a result of one instead of 100. For any value $n$ I can have $n$ comets with periods $T$ orbiting with a gap of $\frac{T}{n}$ time between comets and confuse these $n$ comets for one. If a solution can be shown to be arbitrarily bad it cannot be used for approximations.

Comment: @lPlant I just want to say, that is an **exceptional** justification to why this didn't work. I think I learned more from this comment than from any of the (still good) answers. Would upvote it 100 times I could.

Comment: @IPlant Don't mistake theoretical limitations with practical ones. The probability of having even 2 comets with EXACTLY the same period and being EXACTLY equidistant is negligible. The question was practical: "how could people in olden times have figured out the number of comets".

Comment: @PashaS The question asks us to consider everything at a resolution of years. That's how practical it is. Also, I don't believe you can justify any probabilistic model in a rigorous fashion, or can you? In computer science, we are (unless otherwise stated) interested in absolute truth on an abstract level. And here, the answer is that the problem as modelled can not be solved.

Answer (score -1):

there are many ways to interpret this problem eg as a [machine learning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_learning) problem. however there is some key theory that is relevant & deserves citing, that of the "N-body" problem in physics. this is the problem of predicting motions of objects based on relative gravitational attraction and its an old problem, long studied, and there is a large amount of theory on the subject. the theory originally developed in working to determine trajectories of planets in the solar system and dates at least to Newton. there are surprising new findings also such that there are instabilities and [inherent chaotic dynamics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaos_theory) to these types of equations. in other words predictability may be somewhat like the weather, namely that weather over the short term is moderately predictable but over the long term is not deterministically predictable (because of the so-called [butterfly effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butterfly_effect) etc).

- [N-body problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-body_problem)
- [N-body simulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-body_simulation)

Comment: there is even some evidence for undecidability properties in the n-body problem. eg [Church's thesis meets N-body problem](http://ftp.qucis.queensu.ca/home/akl/cisc879/papers/PAPERS_FROM_APPLIED_MATHEMATICS_AND_COMPUTATION/Special_Issue_on_Hypercomputation/smith%5B1%5D.pdf) / Smith

Comment: While I'd like to think I'm an intelligent individual, this kinda flew way over my head. I got the gist of what you're saying, but not the reasoning.